# Determine new line character used by file in node js

Tags: node.js, file, newline

I am creating a Node app that parses a file but I don't know if it will be using \r\n or \n as the newline character.
I can check the first new line character in the file and see if is \r\n or \n and then store it as my newline variable but is there a more elegant solution?
I know about the {EOL} from os module but that always give \r\n for windows but a window file could be using both \n or \r\n.

Also I don't want to use regex to replace all \r\n with \n for performance reasons.

Answer (score -1):

\n works, I’ve tested it myself.

Comment: The current file that I am testing it on uses \r\n as the new line

Comment: both should work then, no?

Comment: you're right. It would work if I have to count the new line characters but I actually need to remove them. And the file interprets \r as a new line character too.